# VAR model and simulation scenario

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, inflation, forecasting, simulations

I have a VAR model to forecast key economic variables like gdp and inflation, but I want to be able to do some sort of simulation to study a particular scenario.

I am running inflation expectations endogenously within the VAR, and now I want to create a counterfactual scenario where inflation expectations change to see the effect on the forecasts for the key economic variables.

I am not completely sure how I can go about the counterfactual scenario in the easiest way possible. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: What software are you using? Scenarios are fairly simple in eviews.

Comment: @Jamzy using R studio